# opencv - Assertion failed (dst.data == dst0.data) in cvCvtColor

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

The following code will post the error message:

```
// object is a color image with type cv::Mat

IplImage* temp_object = &(IplImage)object;
IplImage* ipl_object = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(temp_object), 8, 3);
assert(temp_object->nChannels ==  3 && temp_object->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U);
assert(ipl_object->nChannels ==  3 && ipl_object->depth == IPL_DEPTH_8U);
cvCvtColor(ipl_object, temp_object, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

**Error**

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dst.data == dst0.data) in cvCvtColor, file /opt/local /var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp, line 3175
>   terminate called throwing an exception`

Updated code after modification (it should work now). Thanks for the help!

```
IplImage temp_object (object);
IplImage* ipl_object = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(&temp_object), 8, 1);
cvCvtColor(&temp_object, ipl_object, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
IplImage* temp_object = &(IplImage)object;
```

That doesn't give you a pointer to `object`, reinterpreted as `IplImage`; instead, it creates a temporary `IplImage` from `object`, gives you a pointer to that, and then destroys the temporary, leaving `temp_object` pointing to nothing valid. Using `temp_object` afterwards will give undefined behaviour.

I'm not familiar with the library, but perhaps you want a pointer to `object` (if `IplImage` is a subtype of whatever type `object` is):

```
IplImage* temp_object = static_cast<IplImage *>(&object);
```

using a cast to convert a pointer (or a reference, if you prefer), not the object itself.

Or maybe you want a new (non-temporary) object:

```
IplImage temp_object(object);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. `IplImage* temp_object = static_cast<IplImage *>(&object);` will give out `error: invalid static_cast from type 'cv::Mat*' to type 'IplImage*'`

Comment: @user1020390: In that case, perhaps you do want to make a new object; you need to give it a name so that it's not temporary. See my edit.

Answer (score 4):

Another issue is that `CV_BGR2GRAY` expects the destination to be a single channel, and not triple. Also, the signature of `cvCvtColor()` starts with SRC and then DST. You probably want to adjust your code to something like:

```
IplImage* ipl_object = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(temp_object), 8, 1);
cvCvtColor(&object, ipl_object, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

Comment: Thanks! I made a mistake in cvCvtColor. Your advice is right. That's what I intend to do. As I also commented above, I cannot create temp_object with the proper type with the line `IplImage* temp_object = static_cast<IplImage *>(&object);`.
The error said it is invalid static_cast. Did I mistake at somewhere?