# Opencv: RGB To HSV

Tags: c, opencv

I write a code to classify color in an image. I compile the code without problem. But when i try to execute it it show me this error.

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dst.data == dst0.data)
in cvCvtColor, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp,
line 3175 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.3.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3175: 
error: (-215) dst.data == dst0.data in function cvCvtColor
```

Any help please on what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maybe the pointer problem. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211696/opencv-assertion-failed-dst-data-dst0-data-in-cvcvtcolor) may help you.

Pay attention to the object definition, and the usage of `cvCvtColor`

Comment: Could you please be more specific and propose a solution? I'm at a loss here, having the same problem... :/ Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of this error comes from type mis-match of input and output image of `cvCvtColor()`. In your example, make sure images `dst` and `dst0` both have at least 3 channels to hold the data.

Also, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211696/opencv-assertion-failed-dst-data-dst0-data-in-cvcvtcolor) for more info.