# Segmentation fault, can't find where I did wrong

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, raspberry-pi

I cannot find where I did wrong in this C++ code for my raspberry pi, it gives me a segmentation fault but after looking for 4 hours and searching here I see nothing wrong

To my knowledge segmentation faults happen when a program is trying to access memory that isn't his, but I don't see this happening anywhere.

I'm basically trying to find a certain coloured object with the raspberry pi module

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "RaspiCamCV.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]){

    RASPIVID_CONFIG * config = (RASPIVID_CONFIG*)malloc(sizeof(RASPIVID_CONFIG));

    config->width=320;
    config->height=240;
    config->bitrate=0;      // zero: leave as default
    config->framerate=0;
    config->monochrome=0;

    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "lxm")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case 'l':                                       // large
                config->width = 640;
                config->height = 480;
                break;
            case 'x':                                       // extra large
                config->width = 960;
                config->height = 720;
                break;
            case 'm':                                       // monochrome
                config->monochrome = 1;
                break;
            default:
                fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-x] [-l] [-m] \n", argv[0], opt);
                fprintf(stderr, "-l: Large mode\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "-x: Extra large mode\n");
                fprintf(stderr, "-l: Monochrome mode\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    /*
     Could also use hard coded defaults method: raspiCamCvCreateCameraCapture(0)
     */
    RaspiCamCvCapture * capture = (RaspiCamCvCapture *) raspiCamCvCreateCameraCapture2(0, config);
    free(config);

    CvFont font;
    double hScale=0.4;
    double vScale=0.4;
    int    lineWidth=1;

    cvInitFont(&font, CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX|CV_FONT_ITALIC, hScale, vScale, 0, lineWidth, 8);

    cvNamedWindow("RaspiCamTest", 1);
    int exit = 0;
    IplImage* x;
    IplConvKernel* erodeElement;
    IplConvKernel* dilateElement;

    printf("start");


    do {
        IplImage* image = raspiCamCvQueryFrame(capture);
        cvCvtColor(image, x, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

        cvInRangeS(&x, cvScalar(0,137,171), cvScalar(48,256,248), x);

        char text[200];
        sprintf(text, "Press ESC to exit");
        cvPutText(x, text, cvPoint(05, 80), &font, cvScalar(255, 255, 0, 0));

        printf("hi");

        erodeElement = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(3,3,-1,-1,MORPH_RECT);
        dilateElement = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(6,6,-1,-1,MORPH_RECT);

        cvErode(x,x,erodeElement);
        cvErode(x,x,erodeElement);

        cvDilate(x,x,dilateElement);
        cvDilate(x,x,dilateElement);



        cvShowImage("RaspiCamTest2", static_cast<CvArr*>(&x));
        cvShowImage("RaspiCamTest", image);

        char key = cvWaitKey(10);

        switch(key)
        {
            case 27:                // Esc to exit
                exit = 1;
                break;
            case 60:                // < (less than)
                raspiCamCvSetCaptureProperty(capture, RPI_CAP_PROP_FPS, 25);    // Currently NOOP
                break;
            case 62:                // > (greater than)
                raspiCamCvSetCaptureProperty(capture, RPI_CAP_PROP_FPS, 30);    // Currently NOOP
                break;
        }

    } while (!exit);

    cvDestroyWindow("RaspiCamTest");
    raspiCamCvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: compile with the -g flag and use gdb to check where the seg fault took place

Comment: Where is x initialized?

Comment: Right before the "do {" line

Comment: @Matthew that isn't *initialized*; that is *declared*. And what is *this*: `static_cast<CvArr*>(&x)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: @Matthew no, it's not initialized there.

Comment: X is initialized in cvCvtColor(image,x,COLOR_BGR2HSV);                        The static_cast is a leftover from trying to convert a Mat to the correct format

Comment: "X is initialized in cvCvtColor(image,x,COLOR_BGR2HSV); " - Again, *no it isn't*. The second parameter to [`cvCvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvcvtcolor#void%20cvCvtColor(const%20CvArr*%20src,%20CvArr*%20dst,%20int%20code)) requires a valid memory address. You're sending it an indeterminate address. The parameter is supposed to be "output image of the same size and depth as src". You're not providing that.

Comment: I thought the x would be initialized inside the method, how would I initialize x in the fastest way, assign null to it?

Comment: Since NULL hardly an "output image of the same size and depth as src", i'm going to go ahead and say *no* to that. You need to create the image target exactly as described; so it has the same size and depth as the source image. Why aren't you using the C++ bindings for OpenCV instead of the C binding, btw? Or is the question miss-tagged?

Comment: In order to get a picture of the raspberry pi camera module you need something else then just opencv, and sadly the thing you need is outdated and gives the old IplImage instead of a Mat, since you can't convert between the 2 that's why everything is using the C equivalent

Comment: sure you can convert between IplImage and cv::Mat. afair it's just: `cv::Mat yourMat = yourIplImage;` or  `cv::Mat yourMat = *yourIplImagePointer;` but I didnt use this for some time, so not 100% sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be the only problem, but `x` is uninitialized when you pass it to `cvCvtColor`. The `dst` pointer you pass to cvCvtColor needs to point to "The destination image of the same data type as the source one." (from [this page](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.3.0.0/html/1e4768b4-c5c5-566f-3ba7-b3ad40dd8817.htm))

This meand the `cvCvtColor` call will write to a random location in memory, possibly causing a crash immediately or later.

Comment: Oh, I thought cvCvtColor would initialize the x, how would I go about initializing x in the fastest way?

Comment: I've never used OpenCV, but a quick google found this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211696/opencv-assertion-failed-dst-data-dst0-data-in-cvcvtcolor which indicates you should use `x = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), 8, 3);` although I am not sure what the `8` and `3` should be.

Comment: Nice catch, `x` should be really initialized. As a rule of thumb, always initialize pointers (at least with `NULL` or `nullptr`) and variables to the appropriate value. OpenCV's C-API doesn't do the initializing of variables (even in case of output parameters) for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the points above:

why do you pass the address of 'x' and 'x' itself in the same function call.

cvInRangeS(>>&x<<, cvScalar(0,137,171), cvScalar(48,256,248), >>x<<);

One of them seems to be incorrect. By passing in &x, do you intend to allocate space and set the pointer. If so, why do you pass in 'x' separately.

Inside the body of cvInRangeS(), the second x will be pointing you to uninitialized memory, even if you fill in the pointer corresponding to the first argument.

This is because all the arguments are evaluated and passed in, including the last parameter as it exists at call-time. The first argument '&x' achieves a side-effect of updating the caller's view, but, it is not available within the body for the second parameter.